# How to use NSNumberFormatter for currency to print in UITextField

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitextfield, uilabel

I am a N00b here .

I print my currency like this :

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed1:(id)sender
    {
        double currency = [Amount1.text doubleValue] + [Amount2.text doubleValue]; 
        SumCurrency.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f", answer];
    }
```

I just simply want to use NSSNumberFormatter to print the SumCurrency.text in US Currency format .. Having a lot of trouble with it ..Please hekp

same issue ??? http://groups.jonzu.com/z_apple_using-a-nsnumberformatter-with-a-uitextfield.html

Thanks in Advance .

Regards ,
N00b

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got the answer .. But for anyone's future reference

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed1:(id)sender {
     double currency = [Amount1.text doubleValue] + [Amount2.text doubleValue]; 
     NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];                
     [numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
     NSString *numberAsString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:currency]];
     SumCurrency.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Converted:%@",numberAsString]; 
}
```

or, in Swift:

```
let amount = 123.56
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale.current
// or
// f.locale = Locale(identifier: "it_IT")
formatter.numberStyle = .currency

let formattedAmountSting = formatter.string(for: amount)!
```

Comment: Please add sample input/output also.

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of a situation where categories in Objective-C shine.

The cleanest solution is to create a category for NSNumber. .h:

```
@interface NSNumber (Formatter)

- (NSString *)currencyStringValue;

@end
```

and .m:

```
@implementation NSNumber (Formatter)

- (NSString *)currencyStringValue
{
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;

    return [formatter stringFromNumber:self];
}

@end
```

In your code, you'd have to #import "NSNumber+Formatter.h" and simply do this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed1:(id)sender
{
    double total = [Amount1.text doubleValue] + [Amount2.text doubleValue];
    NSNumber *totalNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:total];
    SumCurrency.text = totalNumber.currencyStringValue;
}
```

Very clear and clean.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSNumberFormatter * fmt;
NSNumber          * n;

fmt = [ [ NSNumberFormatter alloc ] init ];
n   = [ NSNumber numberWithFloat: 10 ];

[ fmt setFormatterBehavior: NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4 ];
[ fmt setCurrencySymbol: @"$" ];
[ fmt setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle ];

NSLog( @"%@", [ fmt stringFromNumber: n ];

[ fmt release ] /* Thanx willcodejavaforfood... My mistake ; ) */
```

Comment: Hey thanks for that .. I will check that right away . 
I need to put this inside 
-(IBAction)buttonPressed1:(id)sender
{
} 
right ? 
Thanks a ton

Comment: I still cant figure out how to implement in the above code ...
anyone ?? please help

Comment: You first need to get the value you want to display. Then create the formatter, creates the string representation using 'stringFromNumber'. Once you have the NSString, you can do whatever you want. If it's for a UILabel, then just use the 'setText' method...

Comment: How can I use SumCurrency.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f", answer]; to get the answer and not NSLog ?????????????

Comment: @user285096 - i would have told you, but you didnt use enough question marks, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Using float or double (floating point arithmetic) with money is a very bad idea because precision errors. You should use fixed-point arithmetic, aka NSDecimalNumber.

Comment: While that's generally true for data systems, for display purposes the floating-point method perfectly reasonable if all you want to display a number.