# NSString: Validate it is in US currency format

Tags: ios, nsstring, currency

Is there a quick way to validate if an NSString is formatted as US currency?

So what I am looking to confirm is that character 0 is a $, the following characters are numeric except for string.length-3 which could be a decimal (showing the change is optional).

So this passes $1000.00 and this passes $1000 but this would fail $1000B.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369666/how-to-use-nsnumberformatter-for-currency-to-print-in-uitextfield

Comment: you didn't say what you're using this in (a user-editable text field, a static label or?), but in general any answer is likely to make use of NSNumberFormatter

Comment: `^\$\d+(?:\.\d{2})?$`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960300/converting-nsstring-to-currency-the-complete-story

Comment: @iPatel, if any of these related questions are duplicate of this one, you should vote to close this one as a duplicate

Comment: Do you also have the number, or just the formatted string?

Comment: @Michael - It's coming from a UITextField, I am checking it in the textFieldDidEndEditing protocol method...@Marcus - just the formatted string - it's coming from a textfield but the entry could be $1000.00 or 1000 or 1000;C, I want to accept 1 or 2 but not 3.

Answer (score 9):

One simple way would be to validate the string using this regular expression:

```
^[$][0-9]+([.][0-9]{2})?$
^ ^   ^  ^  ^   ^   ^  ^^
| |   |  |  |   |   |  ||
| |   |  |  |   |   |  |+-- End-of-input marker 
| |   |  |  |   |   |  +--- Optional
| |   |  |  |   |   +------ Repeated exactly two times
| |   |  |  |   +---------- A decimal digit
| |   |  |  +-------------- A dot (literal)
| |   |  +----------------- Repeated once or more
| |   +-------------------- A decimal digit
| +------------------------ The dollar sign (literal)
+-------------------------- Start-of-input marker
```

Here is a sample code that uses the above expression:

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
    regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^[$][0-9]+([.][0-9]{2})?$"
                         options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                           error:&error];
if ([regex numberOfMatchesInString:@"$321.05" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, 7)]) {
    NSLog(@"Success");
}
```

Comment: So in your example changing this NSMakeRange(0, string.length) would make it dynamic, right?

Comment: Works in the US. Is there a way generate the regex based on the locale? To match the user's request, I think you'd want a `?` after the `$` also to make it optional. Also, needs to be extended for commas.

Comment: @PruitIgoe That is correct. I hard-coded `7` because I also hard-coded `@"$321.00"`, but in general you need to supply the correct length.

Comment: @MarcusAdams That's by design: the OP asked about US dollars. Using the `NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle` solution will accept `£12.34` in England and `12.34€` in Germany, which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: Great and very complete answer!!

Answer (score 3):

`NSNumberFormatter` not only has `stringFromNumber`, but it also has `numberFromString`.

```
NSString *string = @"$1,000.00";
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSNumber *number = [numberFormatter numberFromString:string];
if (number) {
   // Success
}
```