# UITextfiled validate country currency in between 1 - 100

Tags: ios, objective-c, validation, uitextfield, nsnumberformatter

How to validate UITextfield in between 1 to 100 currency value accepted of maximum 2 decimal values.

Valid.
0.25 99.99, 1.99,100.00.
Other country currency decimal represent , also.
0,25
99,99
1,99
100,00

Invalid 
00.25, 100.25, 0000000.00, 0.125, 9.567

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
    numberFormatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];// this ensures the right separator behavior
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
    numberFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = YES;
    numberFormatter.usesSignificantDigits = YES;
    numberFormatter.currencyGroupingSeparator = numberFormatter.locale.groupingSeparator;
    numberFormatter.decimalSeparator = numberFormatter.locale.decimalSeparator;

NSString *expression = @"^([0-9]+)?(\\.,([0-9]{1,2})?)?$";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:newString
                                                    options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [newString length])];

if (numberOfMatches == 0)
    return NO;
```

not working unable to press , inside UITextfield .    sweden currency decimal represent "," not "." I want work calculation two entered value one is int another value is float

Comment: NSNumberFormatter ?

Comment: Its NSNumberformatter related with currency!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2385041/4601900

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya . Thanks for input's I cross check again my code its problem with my regular expression.      NSString *expression = @"^[0-9]*((\\.|,)[0-9]{0,2})?$";

Answer (score 0):

In the UItTxtfield delegate method try this code.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

    NSInteger Currency = [textField.text integerValue];
    if(Currency >= 100)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *enteredCurrency=textField.text;
        if([enteredCurrency containsString:@"."])
        {
            NSArray *array=[enteredCurrency componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
            if([array[1] length] >= 2 || [array[0] length] >= 2)
            {
                return NO;
            }
            else
            {
                return YES;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return YES;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to implement this by yourlsef since its not scalable. You need to use `NumberFormatter` (or `NSNumberFormatter` for ObjC)

```
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.currency
    formatter.allowsFloats = false
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2  //you get to control how to present the price.
    formatter.locale = locale //This should be the country Locale you need. for example: "en-us"
```

note that `NSLocale` gives you access to also grouping seperator and decimal separator, so you can check it later if you like.

`formatter.currencyGroupingSeparator = locale.groupingSeparator
 formatter.decimalSeparator = locale.decimalSeparator`

Comment: I dont' really understand your updated question.. Can you clarify please?

Comment: after worked out found issue is related with regular expression!

Comment: For future reference, please edit your question by adding the correct regex.